# Reference to an automated nachash who goes to the market for you?

Tags: midrash, messianic-redemption

I’m searching for a reference to the place in the Gemara which talks about there being, in the messianic era, some kind of helper which I think is the nachash which goes to the store and the marketplace to pick up goods so you don’t have to.

Where is this source? I can’t seem to find it on Google and I don’t remember where it was the first time I saw it.

Answer (score 2):

The [gemara](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.59b.21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) in Sanhedrin 59b says:

דתניא ר"ש בן מנסיא אומר חבל על שמש גדול שאבד מן העולם שאלמלא (לא) נתקלל נחש כל
אחד ואחד מישראל היו מזדמנין לו שני נחשים טובים אחד משגרו לצפון ואחד משגרו לדרום להביא לו סנדלבונים טובים ואבנים טובות ומרגליות ולא עוד אלא שמפשילין רצועה תחת זנבו ומוציא בה עפר לגנתו ולחורבתו

As it is taught in a baraita that Rabbi Shimon ben Menasya says: Woe over a great attendant that has been lost to the world; as had the snake not been cursed that it should go on its belly, there would have been two fine snakes at the disposal of each and every one of the Jewish people. One he would send to the north, and the other one he would send to the south, to bring him precious sandalbonim, a type of precious stone, and other precious stones and pearls. Moreover, he would attach a strap under his snake’s tail like a harness to an animal, and use it to take dirt out to his garden and to rebuild his ruin, as he does with other animals. This demonstrates that the snake was capable of performing labor.

Comment: Wonderful!! This is the source I was looking for! Thank you! May the redemption from the זוהמה come soon